# Asterisk voicemail wrong time stamp always at UTC format

Tags: datetime, timezone, asterisk, voicemail

I installed asterisk to make a voicemail server.
functions are all working unless in timeformat. here's scenario.

When i dial no. and record for voicemail it emails me a right timeformat but in msg.txt 
its always show **UTC format**.

**Server time.**

> Tuesday, 01 October, 2013 11:09:35 AM PHT  -1.042756 seconds

**asterisk voicemail.conf**

> tz=ph
>   [zonemessages]
>   ph=Asia/Manila|'vm-received' Q 'digits/at' IMp

**asterisk extension.conf**

> exten => _XXX,1,Answer()
>   exten => _XXX,2,AGI(sample.agi)
>   exten => _XXX,3,VoiceMail(${VMNUMBER},u,tz=ph)
>   exten => _XXX,4,Playback(vm-goodbye)
>   exten => _XXX,5,Hangup()

**asterisk -rx "core show version"**

> Asterisk 11.5.1 built by root@asterisk on a x86_64 running Linux on 2013-10-01 02:31:27 UTC

**vim msg000X.txt in voicemail folder**

> callerid="1234" <1234>
>   origdate=Tue Oct  1 **02:47:36 AM UTC** 2013
>   origtime=1380595656

thanks in advance
Owen

Comment: Why u think that is problem? Asterisk always save time in GMT. But have play in specified format(sure if you configured ok and not did syntax errors)

Comment: hi @arheops, yup theres no syntax error. i always monitor asterisk in debug mode but still can get what the cause of problem btw i had a web-based voicemail that read msg.txt.

Comment: so you need fix web,not asterisk.

Comment: No sir, in other forum i read about that they having a same issue with me. my app only reading the msg00x.txt and display to web.

Comment: if asterisk plaiing ok, your app have check tonezone. asterisk have do nothing here.

Comment: if you familiar in vmail.cgi app, i used that.

Comment: Sorry, if you use third-party agi, you need patch thoose agi to support your timezone.

Comment: which one do i need to patch my database server? or the asterisk server? thanks for the info sir..

Comment: You need patch agi-file. So it start recognize your timezones.

Comment: http://forums.asterisk.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=88151 Sir, here my scenario. thanks,

Comment: Again, that is normal behovour(and documented) of asterisk. I am afraid asterisk comunity can't change it for your need, becuase it will result "broken" much more system then your single one. You have change agi script.

Comment: ohh.. so i need to make a agi script that convert the UTC format to PHT timezone?

Comment: No. You need adapt your voicemail.cgi to check timezone and change time acordinly.

Comment: Thanks for the Info sir, now im done with my voicemail. thanks a lot.. i made a shellscript to convert from UTC to localformat

Answer (score 0):

```
root@server:/usr/local/etc/asterisk # date
```

Wed Oct  9 09:47:54 COT 2013

```
root@server:/usr/local/etc/asterisk # asterisk -rx "core show version"
```

Asterisk 11.5.1 built by root @ mydomain.com on a amd64 running FreeBSD on 2013-10-08 04:09:27 UTC